# How browsers work on upload multiple file parts asynchronously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, safari

I'm designing and implementing split one big file into small chunks for upload.

I've tried chunk size for 1mb, 10mb, 100mb for uploading 1gb, 10gb files.

I tested it on Chrome browser and not found specific performance difference among above different chunk size.

Quick questions here. If I choose chunk size as 1mb for upload 10GB file.
There will be 10K chunks to upload. Is there any limitation for IE, Chrome, or Safari for doing this intensive task?

Usually, how many workers/threads will be using for uploading at a time?

Thanks a lot!

```
for(let chunkIndex=0; chunkIndex< LAST_CHUNK_INDEX ;chunkIndex++) {
    SEND_CHUNK[chunkIndex] // Using axios or xhr for uploading files.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I haven't found any official document about limitation for chunks numbers about browsers. But it sometimes might have limitation when using some tool to upload to somewhere specific, [like this](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1697).
2. About the working principle, we send each chunk as a separate request. 
   I found [a sample](https://gist.github.com/shiawuen/1534477) of uploading file by chunk. And I found [the comment made by rizsi](https://gist.github.com/shiawuen/1534477#gistcomment-2271415) is very useful:

   > The main reason for chunked upload is that the server does not need to store the whole file in memory - which is also possible to work around on the server side when data is streamed to file directly, the second reason is to make big file upload resumable in case the TCP stream breaks.
   >
   > So we should send each chunk after the previous one has finished. If we send all chunks at once, it would flood the server with all the pieces at once making the whole thing pointless.

Comment: Hello Zhou~~ really appreciate your sharing! 謝謝～